# Preloading Ecto Associations by default

Tags: elixir, ecto

Is there any way to preload ecto associations without explicitly using preload:?

Something like an option in the schema?

```
schema "gadgets" do
  field :foo,
  has_many :bars, Myapp.Bar, preload: true
end
```

I'm doing something like

```
Repo.get(Gadget, id)
  |> Repo.preload: [:bars]
```

Edit: the reason I'm trying to do this is because I want to preload a related model to the already preloaded related model, like

```
 preload: [:invoices preload: :items]
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can also preload as part of a query:

```
defmodule Gadget do
  use Ecto.Model

  # ...

  def with_invoices(query) do
    from q in query, preload: [invoices: :items]
  end
end
```

Then:

```
Gadget
|> Gadget.with_invoices
|> Repo.get!(id)
```

Comment: Is there any reason it isn't an option in the schema?  I know it is nice to preserve the option whether to preload or not when querying, but for certain related models you always need it preloaded.  On mine, the invoice totals are calculated from the items, which won't work if not preloaded.

Comment: Given reply does not really answer the question. I found it annoying to always remember about explicit preload certain models. What was the thought behind making it explicit?

Comment: @Jared Because otherwise you get n+1 queries. If you load 100 rows with an association, instead of 2 queries, you're now doing 101. So it's worth thinking about to avoid the extra 99 queries.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure it is the fastest way, but I ended up doing this using the after_load callback, like this:

```
defmodule Invoice do
  use Ecto.Model

  after_load :preload_items

  def preload_items(invoice) do
    invoice |> Repo.preload([:items])
  end
end
```

Now, every time Invoice is loaded, even if it is preloaded by something else, it will preload its associated items.

**Edit - Don't do this**

Put the preloads in the query instead.  retrieving 1000 invoices with above code will result in 1 + 1000 queries.  the preload in the query adds 0NE.
query.  1 + 1 < 1000 + 1.

```
  query = from c in Gadget,
  #retrieve nested associations adds one query
  preload: [invoices: :items]
  select c

Repo.all(query)
```

Comment: Don't do this. This will do a query per invoice. So if you load 10 invoices in a query, it will do 10 separate queries to load items.

Comment: Callbacks have been removed from Elixir